# Gulp 'clean' giving error on second run

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a pretty simple (or so I thought) gulpfile for a web app I am writing, the main function moves all the files from the `src` directory to the `build` directory, processing certain files along the way. It's set up so it runs when gulp starts and then watches the `src` directory for changes and runs again whenever one occurs. It runs perfectly fine on the first run through, but then whenever it runs from the `watch` function it returns this error:

`Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/sawyer/Desktop/Web Scraper/online/build/css/styles.css'`

Here is my gulpfile (note it gives the same error without chmod as well):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');

gulp.task('default', ['buildProjectFiles'], function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*', ['buildProjectFiles']);
});

gulp.task('buildProjectFiles', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('moveFiles');
    gulp.start('processSCSS');
    gulp.start('processJS');
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    var clean = require('gulp-clean');

    return gulp.src('build/**/*', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('moveFiles', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.php', 'src/**/*.json', 'src/fonts/*', 'src/img/*'], {base: 'src'})
        .pipe(chmod(766))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('processSCSS', function() {
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');

    return gulp.src('src/scss/*.scss', {base: 'src/scss'})
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(chmod(766))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('processJS', function() {
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js', {base: 'src'})
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(chmod(766))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Any ideas?

Edit: even using `clean({force: true})` does not work

Edit 2: From my testing, I have found that it is not a problem with the watch, but rather every other time it is run, no matter when it runs. It works fine by disabling either `moveFiles` or `processSCSS`.

Comment: I sorta solved it by replacing `gulp-clean` with `del` but I still have no idea why `gulp-clean` doesn't work when it's worked for me before.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try changing the `buildProjectFiles` to something like this :

```
gulp.task('buildProjectFiles', ['clean'], function(callback) {
    gulp.start(['moveFiles', 'processSCSS', 'processJS'], callback);
});
```

Otherwise I think gulp doesn't know when `buildProjectFiles` actually finishes and there might be some tasks overlapping with clean.